# Windows batch: date format variable not printing correctly

Tags: windows, date, batch-file

So i have  this code.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('dateFormat +"%Y/%m/%d %T"') DO SET Now=%%A
CALL run_some_job "%Now%"
```

my output.

```
JOB_FILE_PATH>FOR /F "tokens=*" %A IN ('dateFormat +"m/T"
') DO SET Now=%A

JOB_FILE_PATH>SET Now=m/T

JOB_FILE_PATH>CALL run_some_job  m/T
```

I use the dateFormat tool from date.exe in this. 
http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ to print date.  If i do dateFormat +"%Y/%m/%d %T", than it works correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the percent signs in the date format argument:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('c:\utils\date +"%%Y/%%m/%%d %%T"') DO SET Now=%%A
```